# Finishing a narrow cavity

Tags: finishing, sanding, tool-selection

This is a continuation from [my previous question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/carving-a-wooden-handle-any-rules-of-thumb) on the log box I've been carving. Since then I've carved the handle (thanks for the advice!) and added a magnet closure system for my swivel lid (neodymium rings fastened in place with aluminum nails).

See the pictures below for a look.

I feel like I've got the exterior where I want it to be, but I'm having trouble finishing the cavity to a level where it's visually "clean." I've been working it mainly with hand tools and my Dremel. The interior cavity is roughly 4.25" deep and a about 3.25" across, which means the narrowness limits the work space.

Will I have to spend an eternity sanding, or is there another way to work out the tool marks?

[image: Side profile with view of handle carved out]
[image: Top down picture of the closure system and rough interior]

Answer (score 3):

This is probably going to be tough any way you cut it. I would suggest a combination of curved card scraper and something like [these abrasive brushes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001F527F0), possibly mounted on a long or flex shaft to get into the cavity.
[image: Abrasive brushes from Amazon]

Comment: *Any way you cut it* \*groan* :-)

Comment: The cavity doesn't really have a consistent curve... does it matter what the specific curve of the card scraper is?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky to an extent, yes. Keep in mind both french curve shaped scrapers, and the fact that you can file a scraper to any shape you please.

Comment: @aaron Thanks for the advice. I'm considering grabbing these: http://www.stewmac.com/Luthier_Tools/Types_of_Tools/Scrapers/Scraper_Blades.html http://www.stewmac.com/Luthier_Tools/Types_of_Tools/Scrapers/StewMac_Ultimate_Scraper.html From what I've read they're pretty decent. These will be my first scrapers... Any advice on technique for working in such a narrow space?

Comment: interesting. those thick ones are new to me. I'd recommend getting some regular ones (for example, http://www.stewmac.com/Luthier_Tools/Types_of_Tools/Scrapers/Scraper_Blades.html) because they are general purpose and these are the type that can be filed to whatever shape very easily.